# Echarts как изменить цвет symbol после наведения мыши

Tags: график

Есть echarts график, type = line, при наведении мыши хочу менять цвет symbol. Но никак не могу найти решение.

```
series: [
       {
         data: this.graphicData.map(res => res.count),
         type: 'line',
         symbol: 'circle',
         symbolSize: 6,
         itemStyle: {
           color: `#607880`,
         },
       }
     ]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я разобрался, что бы при наведении мыши точки подкрашивались необходимым цветом нужно в itemstyle добавить

```
emphasis: {
  color: 'red'
          }
```